# No idea where seg fault is occuring

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

For some reason, when I run this code, I get a seg fault when the value of i in the for-loop is 7654319. However the strange thing is that when I am not checking if the value is pan-digital, it works normally without a segfault. It also works when I am checking if it is just pandigital; but not for both. I used gdb to step through the code and here is the output I get:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004007d3 in main () at Pand.cc:81
81      if (isPandigital(i) && Primes[i])
6: Primes[i] = <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffefffffff4>
5: i = <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffefffffff4>
4: Primes[7654317] = <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffefffffff8>
3: Primes[7654321] = <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffefffffff8>
2: Primes[7654319] = <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffefffffff8>
1: Primes = <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x7ffefffffff8>
```

From the output, it seems that by manipulating the value of i in the `isPandigital(int)` function, this also affects value of i in main. This didn't make any sense to me, but I went ahead and used a different variable to represent i in the `isPandigital(int)` function, but I still get the same error.

Can someone help me please? These kind of errors are so annoying because everything seems like it should be working, but it's not and the solution is just hiding itself under layers of implementation. Any help is appreciated!

```
#include <cstdio>
#define MAX 7700000

typedef unsigned int uint;

bool* GetPrimes()
{  
  const int Need = MAX;
  bool* Sieve = new bool[Need];

  for (int s = 0; s < Need; ++s)
    Sieve[s] = 1;

  bool Done = false;
  uint w = 3;

  while (!Done)
  {  
    for (uint q = 3, Prod = w * q; Prod < (uint)Need ; q += 2, Prod = w * q)
      Sieve[Prod] = false;

    Done = (w > (Need >> 1) ? true : false);

    w+=2;
  }
  return Sieve;
}

bool isPandigital(int num)
{
  int arr [] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}, G, count = 7;
  do
  {
    G = num%10;
    if (arr[G-1])
      --count;
    arr[G-1] = 0;
  } while (num/=10);

  return (!count);
}

int main()
{  
  bool* Prime = GetPrimes();
  int i;

  for (i = 7654321 ;i > 2; i-=2)
  {
    if (Prime[i] && isPandigital(i))
      break;
  }

  printf("%d\n", i); 

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered debugging?

Comment: although it is irrelevant to your segfault, you should notice that you don't free the memory when done with it.

Comment: also, are you working on http://projecteuler.net/problem=41 by any chance? :)

Comment: Yes I have considered this, which is why I used gdb to step through it and was able to find out which number was causing the error - This is basically the next number after the first one in the for-loop - 7654319

And yes Jake223 that is what I am working on

Comment: Jake223, considering your free memory comment. I have tried doing this before, but the compiler gave a warning that this is done automatically; so I just left it as is

Comment: You are not showing us the actual code that has the problem - the line of code reported in the stack trace isn't the same as in the code you posted. Please fix that.

Comment: I changed the variable name of primes to prime...that seems to be the only thing missing. The code I have now is exactly the same as the one I posted plus I removed some comments I have put in the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `isPandigital` function. Notice that if `num` is a multiple of ten or congruent to `8` or `9` mod `10`, you'll have a few problems. Out-of-bounds array accesses often lead to segfaults.

The first prime for which this occurs is 19 (or 7654319 if you go backwards from 7654321):

```
bool isPandigital(int num)//num is (76543)19
{
  int arr [] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}, G, count = 7;
  do
  {
    G = num%10;        //G is 9
    if (arr[G-1])      //G-1 is 8; G is only indexed from 0 to 6.
      --count;            
    arr[G-1] = 0;      //G-1 is 8; G is only indexed from 0 to 6.
  } while (num/=10);

  return (!count);
}
```

Note that though the *solution* will not have an 8 or 9 in it, any prime you test might.

Comment: `G = num%10;` will actually be `9` for `num = 19`.

Comment: OMG dude, you are legend! I will try fixing that right away!

Comment: Thanks - it always helps to get an extra set of eyes on your code :)

Answer (score 1):

Look at:

```
 G = num%10;
    if (arr[G-1])
```

So, what if `G` is zero? This would also trash your stack, making debug hard.

On the face of it, `isPandigital` works nicely in the case when the number passed is pan-digital, else has an array bound under/overrun?

Comment: Inside the for loop it will never be because `num` is always going to be an odd number.

Comment: Well, I'd be making a check/assert on that assumption.

Comment: Still it is not the cause of segfault.

Comment: I don't believe that is the problem. I have used the function to find all pandigitals from 123456789 to 123987654 and I never got a seg fault doing that. It is something else less obvious

I tried doing this

if (G){
      if (arr[G-1])} And I still get the error

Comment: What about `7654109`, which is prime?

Comment: Thanks for that Keith. I have gone ahead and fixed that. It is working now thanks to both you and Jake223. Thank you all who helped with this; fastest problem solving team eva!